# Is there any agreement or consent in the order arguments should be passed to a class's constructor?

Tags: c#, c++, coding-style

I was wondering if it is a good practice to pass the arguments that are needed for construction of the base class first or last when defining the constructor's signature of a derived class that passes arguments to the constructor of the first class:

```
public class Base
{
    private Type1 _t1;
    private Type2 _t2;

    Base(Type1 t1, Type2 t2)
    {
        _t1 = t1;
        _t2 = t2;
    }
}
```

Option 1:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    private Type3 _t3;
    private Type4 _t4;

    // Base class arguments first in the signature
    public Derived(Type1 t1, Type2 t2, Type3 t3, Type4 t4) : Base(t1, t2)
    {
        _t3 = t3;
        _t4 = t4;
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    private Type3 _t3;
    private Type4 _t4;

    // Derived class arguments first in the signature
    public Derived(Type3 t3, Type4 t4, Type1 t1, Type2 t2) : Base(t1, t2)
    {
        _t3 = t3;
        _t4 = t4;
    }
}
```

Though I know it doesn't make any difference to the compiler is there anything said about this in good programming practices? Which approach is preferred, if any?

Comment: Entirely opinion based. If one were more efficient than the other, the compiler would rearrange it for you anyway.

Comment: @Barry: arguments cannot be freely reordered by the compiler (unless the whole function is inlined), as they affect the ABI.

Answer (score 1):

The question is bogus as you are thinking in the wrong terms. You are considering `Derived` as being a `Base` and something else. You should instead be thinking on `Derived` as being substitutible for `Base`.  The constructor parameters for `Derived` are those of the derived type, what arguments the constructor of `Base` takes are completely irrelevant. At this point the question is, what would the proper order of `Derived`'s arguments `t1`, `t2`, `t3`...

The caller need not and should not be aware of how you are initializing the `Base`, only how they can parametrize `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW. I concur. Totally opinion based.
However. Notation-wise. And Personally. In those cases where numbers are involved (like in your example), maintaining a number order (ascending or otherwise) is a good rule of thumb. So.

```
t1, t2, t3, t4 ...
```

instead of

```
t3, t4, t1, t2 ...
```

Comment: Pretty sure `t1`, `t2`, ... are just arbitrary placeholders and the variables themselves have real names.

Comment: Agreed. But. As it was no stated, and, in those cases where numbers are indeed involved, and generically, "disturbing" the number order isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I think matters here is if you could have some constructor in the derived class with optional arguments. For example:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    private static Type4 DEFAULT_T4_VALUE = something;

    private Type3 _t3;
    private Type4 _t4;

    // Base class arguments first in the signature
    public Derived(Type1 t1, Type2 t2, Type3 t3, Type4 t4 = null) : Base(t1, t2)
    {
        _t3 = t3;
        if (t4 == null) _t4 = DEFAULT_T4_VALUE;
        else _t4 = t4;
    }
}
```